# Nexus Sonatype error

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I have recently copied third-party folder of sonatype from nexus 2.0.5 (which was installed on suse linux) to nexus 2.7.0-06(on redhat linux server) but while browsing the folder in nexus repository it throws the error "Nexus returned an error: ERROR 500: Server Error". I did a search for this and found the replies as disk space issue but that's not the case here. We have enough disk space. On checking the logs, I see Access denied issue but not sure why its coming I can successfully login into nexus using my LDAP credentials.Here is the error message: Please advise.

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/local/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/thirdparty/.nexus/attributes/test/test-requestor-ejb/maven-metadata.xml.md5
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:441) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1345) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.storage.local.fs.DefaultFSPeer.handleRenameOperation(DefaultFSPeer.java:363) ~[nexus-core-2.7.0-06.jar:2.7.0-06]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.storage.local.fs.DefaultFSPeer.storeItem(DefaultFSPeer.java:160) ~[nexus-core-2.7.0-06.jar:2.7.0-06]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permissions in /usr/local/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/thirdparty/.nexus/attributues, it looks like the user running nexus doesn't have permissions to write into that area.